# Inverted y-axis in barplot in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, yaxis

I am attempting to create a barplot of Depth as a function of time with the y-axis as an inverted variable.

Here are the data and what I have already tried:

```
print(time)   
     X TIMEBIN    Depth       sd
1   1    0:00 18.00406 2.781441
2   2    1:00 17.96074 2.817540
3   3    2:00 17.97180 2.778820
4   4    3:00 18.01903 2.782083
5   5    4:00 18.00780 2.734043
6   6    5:00 18.17569 2.636813
7   7    6:00 18.68155 2.614985
8   8    7:00 18.69972 2.979700
9   9    8:00 18.52856 3.122060
10 10    9:00 18.55019 3.143108
11 11   10:00 18.51772 3.269256
12 12   11:00 18.61536 3.191887
13 13   12:00 18.66978 3.173669
14 14   13:00 18.61723 3.231002
15 15   14:00 18.55546 3.265940
16 16   15:00 18.58414 3.265866
17 17   16:00 18.50632 3.282407
18 18   17:00 18.39582 3.261294
19 19   18:00 18.61803 3.119812
20 20   19:00 18.68454 2.737240
21 21   20:00 18.66503 2.486053
22 22   21:00 18.11435 2.655190
23 23   22:00 17.98060 2.692461
24 24   23:00 17.97625 2.772666


barplot(time$Depth,beside=TRUE, ylim=c(21,18),ylab="Depth (m)", xlab='Time')

plot(time$Depth~time$TIMEBIN,type='h', ylim=rev(c(18,21)),ylab="Depth (m)", xlab='Time')
```

I am simply trying to get the bars to attach to the bottom of the graph at 21 as well as get the x-axis to appear as 1:24 but nothing else I have tried seems to work and these graphs are the closest I can get.

This is what I keep getting:
[image: Actual Result]

And this is what I want:
[image: Desired Result]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you reversing the y-axis? Does `ylim=c(18,21)` in `barplot` not work? And the gap is because data starts at zero.

Comment: I'm attempting to reverse the y-axis because the parameter is water depth and increasing depth as you go down is intuitive to readers. And no, 'ylim = c(18,21)' doesn't work either.

Comment: Then please explain *bars to attach to the bottom of the graph at 21*. Shouldn't they be at the top? Can you add an image like a manually sketched graph to show your desired result?

Comment: I have added two images of what I keep getting and what I would like the desired result to be.

Comment: I am unable to render your desired result. Reverting y-axis like that to start at zero is asking to manipulate the data. I can re-write axis labels but bars will not align to such values and I can help show 1-24 on x-axis. Come to think of it, I am not quite sure about this: *increasing depth as you go down is intuitive to readers*. Consider showing as data defines it (click Run): https://rextester.com/FEP50522. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Hopefully, I can get it to work.